# passing url from a form to a different form which contains web browser control

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I'm trying to pass a url from one Form to another Form (both are in the same project).

The first form contains a web browser control in it. It also has a button, on press of a button the second form launches. The second form just has a button with hard coded url. when the user clicks on the button the url should be passed to the first form and the webbrowser should navigate to the link. Below is the simple code I'm trying

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void loadwebpage(string link)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(link);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondForm form2 = new secondForm();
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class secondForm : Form
{
    public secondForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Form1 form1= new Form1();
        form1.loadwebpage("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

The above code is not working, the webbrowser control does not navigate to the google page. can anyone help

Comment: You need the existing instance.

Comment: @SLaks How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the first form as a parameter to your second form. On your second form, you could create a property on your class that matches the type of the first form.

In the constructor of the second form, set said property.

When the user clicks the button on the second form, reference the property of the class that has been set to the instance of the first form and call your loadwebpage function.

EDIT:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void loadwebpage(string link)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(link);
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondForm form2 = new secondForm(this);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
public partial class secondForm : Form
{
    public Form1 form1 { get; set;}
    public secondForm(Form1 f)
    {
        form1 = f;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

        form1.loadwebpage("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a small example

Comment: Check out the edit to the post, I think that should work.. I didn't test it.